# How can I migrate from Forestry.io to Contentful CMS

Tags: content-management-system, hugo, contentful, contentful-api

I want to migrate from Forestry.io(https://forestry.io/)  to Contentful CMS as Forestry.io will be discontinued in March.
I had used Forestry.io and Hugo as static site generator, but now I want to migrate my CMS to Contentful.
Please help me how can I do this, I couldn't find any migration guide

Comment: Hey Ankit, you can use Contentful's Content Management API to programmatically migrate your content to Contentful. Once you have migrated the content, you can use Contentful's Content Delivery API in your site to fetch the content.

Comment: Forestry.io is a git based CMS. It is easier to move to another git based CMS, like CloudCannon.